# Extending neo4j with new index structures

Tags: indexing, neo4j

Suppose I want to implement a new index structure (e.g., `BITMAT`) that will improve the efficiency of some queries (Path queries for the `BITMAT` case). How do I extend `Neo4j` so that every query with a specified query pattern uses my new index instead of Neo4j's native index?

Comment: what is your specified query pattern, and also your environment (java, python, console only ...)?

Comment: The programming environment is Java. The specified query pattern depends on the index. For instance, a bitmat index is often used for fast evaluation of query patterns of the form a --> b, a --> c where let's say b is bound and we retrieve the values of c from the index,  without having to traverse the graph at query time. I can add my index as a separate algorithm. The real question is how we can inform the CYPHER query processor to use my index as part of its standard query evaluation process.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can implement a new IndexProvider that hooks into the normal Neo4j indexing system. This is then automatically exposed to Cypher. You can see an example of this in this SpatialIndexProvider, projecting a subgraph query into an index lookup and run Cypher queries against it:

https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/indexprovider/LayerNodeIndex.java

Test with Cypher:

https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/IndexProviderTest.java#L141

Comment: Feel free to blog about your work, would be super-interesting!